# Java convert user's input by adding zeroes into following format XX.xxxxxx

Tags: javascript, java

I have a client side validation done in JavaScript where it converts the user's input value by adding the zeroes if user enters one digit before the decimal or less than 6 digits after the decimal. For instance:

- 2.45 converts into -> 02.450000
- Data entry of 0 (this includes 0.0 or 0.00 or 0.000 etc) is not a valid value

by using the logic below in JavaScript:

```
const formatInput = (input) => {
  const [base, dec] = input.split('.');
  let value = (!+base ? base : base.padStart(2, '0')) + '.' + (dec || '').padEnd(6, '0');
  return value;
};
console.log(formatInput('2.45'))
```

Now I am trying to achieve the same result in JAVA. How can I implement the same logic in JAVA on the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly and I also don't get why the input is so limited to these certain amounts of digits but whatever. I tried to quickly put together a quite ugly solution, which is in no way optimized.

I tried to limit the input to the way I understood your description, and focus on building the input as you described. So it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(formatInput("0.060"));
    System.out.println(formatInput("10.4960"));
    System.out.println(formatInput("1.99"));
    System.out.println(formatInput("9"));
    System.out.println(formatInput("29.666666"));
    System.out.println(formatInput("0.0"));
}

private static String formatInput(String input) {
    String result = "";
    String[] parts = input.split("\\.");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if ((input == null) || (input.isEmpty()) || (!input.matches(".*[1-9].*")) || (parts.length < 1) || (parts.length > 2)
            || (parts[0].length() > 2) || (parts.length == 2 && parts[1].length() > 6)) { // filtering out the invalid cases
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        return result;
    }
    if (parts[0].length() == 1) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
    sb.append(parts[0]).append('.');
    if (parts.length == 2) { // input is of value xx.xx
        sb.append(parts[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6 - parts[1].length(); i++) { // pad remaining zeroes
            sb.append('0');
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } else if (parts.length == 1) { // input is of value x or xx
        sb.append("000000");
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
00.060000
10.496000
01.990000
09.000000
29.666666
Invalid input.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to convert input value into desired format and then store it into a string to preserve the format. Following is the sample code snippet

```
   public void formatInput() {
    double input = 2.45;
    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("00.000000");
    String formattedInput = String.valueOf(df.format(input));
    System.out.println("Formatted text: " + formattedInput);
}
```

And the output is

```
Formatted text: 02.450000
```

Edit 1: As @saka1029 mentioned, you can use String.format for one time use.

Comment: You can get the same result with `String.format("%09.6f", input)`.

Comment: Yes String.format is simple and based on the usecase one can use String.format over DecimalFormat. At least I can think of 2 reasons to use DecimalFormat. 1. If formatter requires on more than one field of more than one time then better to create DecimalFormat instance and reuse.String.format creates Formatter instance every time 2. DecimalFormat respects Locale